# Hide the port when node.js is running

Tags: node.js

how can I hide the port when I ran my node application

example

http://localhost:3000/application/login

What I need is to hide port 3000 so that it stays that way

http://localhost/application/login

Comment: Use port 80 instead?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phrasing it a bit differently.

When you open a http:// url, browsers will by default use port 80. Only if you specify a port, browsers will try a different port instead.

So if you don't want the port to appear in the url, you must use port 80.

Comment: excludes virtualhost

Comment: @VincentAlex 'virtual host' is not a concept in HTTP the protocol. If you use virtualhosts or not, this is all still true. The only case where it's not true is if SRV records are used.

Comment: I have the same issue; different web services: host:101/app1, host:102/app2 but need a common interface (port 80) host/app1, host/app2
Can this be done with websockify?

Comment: I don't know websockify, but most people handle this through their webservice configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the server on port 80, but to do this, you need root privileges, and it used to be a bad idea.